# Is it possible to consume a web service in a c++ service application

Tags: c++, web-services, service, wsdl, ambiguity

I am trying to consume a web service in my c++ service application using the WSDL importer. I can import the web service but as soon as I want to use some of the webmethods by including service.h in my file I get the following error:

> Unit1.cpp(64): E2015 Ambiguity between 'Soap::Wsdlbind::TService' and 'Vcl::Svcmgr::TService'

I imported this web service to a VCL forms application and that worked perfectly.

I am using RAD Studio XE2. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That simply means that you have a name clash in your code, i.e. you have somewhere something like

```
//Header names should be different, just for the sake of the example
#include Soap/Wsdlbin/TService.h
#include Vcl/Svcmgr/TService.h
<some namespace using directives>
...

TService service;
```

And the compiler cannot determine which `TService` it is. You have to qualify `TService` so that the compiler know which to use, i.e.:

```
Soap::Wsdlbind::TService service;
//or
Vcl::Svcmgr::TService service;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I should have known this!